# javascript wizard/assistant plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins, wizard, assistant

I wonder if someone knows a javascript pluging (preferably for jQuery) to create MS word like wizards or assistant. To better explain what I want is a plugin for introducing a web site to new users, showing some message to do something and blinking in the links or buttons that they have to press to do it.

I remember seeing one some time ago but I cannot find now and googling is hard with these terms.

Comment: I found a very interesting jQuery plugin: guidely [link](http://codecanyon.net/item/guidely-jquery-website-tours/372309)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try http://amberjack2.org/. However the Library is not documented yet. You'll have to look at the source to see how to implement it.

Just found another library which appears to be easier: http://tympanus.net/Development/WebsiteTour/

Here are posts that talks about it:

- http://tympanus.net/codrops/2010/12/21/website-tour/
- http://www.codediesel.com/javascript/creating-website-tours-using-jquery/

Answer (score 3):

You could also use the original Microsoft assistants ported to JavaScript:

- Clippy
- Merlin
- Rover
- and Links

https://www.smore.com/clippy-js

PS: I would definitely not use that on a serious page ;)

Answer (score 0):

I found a couple more:

- http://mstratman.github.io/jQuery-Smart-Wizard/
- http://exacttarget.github.io/fuelux/#wizard
- http://www.dbarnes.info/jWizard/#demo

Hope this helps